# Connecting NodeJS to Atlas MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have some script that I have made in order to create a server and database by using NodeJS and MongoDB.

I have tried the code by using localhost and everything works fine.

I have created an account at Atlas MongoDB in order to test the application on online database.

I changed the url in my js as it was giving by Atlas when connection string only:

```
const url = "mongodb+srv://XXX:<XXX>@XXX-uyrjt.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

MongoClient.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err,client) {

    if(err)
        console.log('unable to connect to mongodb server.error',err);
    else{...

}
```

However I get the following Error:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you provided the right username and pass?

Comment: https://codeforgeek.com/mongodb-atlas-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

Please double check 2 things here

1. Correct username & Password
2. Your ip is white listed in Atlas Account. to disable white listing you can use ip - 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Checked and both are ok. I read somewhere that it might be because of the use of useNewUrlParser: true but found it only in one place